# How do you request the DynamoDB.DocumentClient service in a plugin?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless-plugins

To make AWS requests in a plugin, you can do something like this:

```js
  constructor(serverless, options) {
    ...
    this.provider = serverless.getProvider('aws');
  }
    ...
  hook() {
    ...
    await this.provider.request('S3', 'put', params);
  }
```

How do you request `DynamoDB.DocumentClient`?

Looking at [awsProvider.js](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/8e022ba3fe6b6f857be6096bb6c0718d0e6f244a/lib/plugins/aws/provider/awsProvider.js#L287), it seems like there is no way to do so. If so, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now supported in Serverless `1.59.0`: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/releases/tag/v1.59.0 (code change: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/7031)

Comment: I am attempting to deploy an express.js server in netlify based on your blog post: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/09/13/how-to-run-express.js-apps-with-netlify-functions/. Would you be willing to take a look at the following issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868667/how-to-deploy-express-js-server-to-netlify